# Is there a better way than using a generic WildCard as a method parameter?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I need my getNextId() method for three different maps:

```
private final Map<Integer, Track> tracks;
private final Map<Integer, Train> trains;

private final Map<Integer, Coach> coaches;
```

So far, I had three different methods but that's obviously unnecessary. Is there a better way than using the generic wildcard `?` if the method only needs to be working for the above maps?

```
public int getNextId(Map<Integer, ?> givenMap) {
            int id = 1;
        for (int key : givenMap.keySet()) {
            if (key > id) break;
            id = key + 1;
        }
        return id;
}
```

The getNextId() method basically gets the smallest available ID >=1. If trainIDs 1, 2, 3, 4 exist and the user deletes train with ID 2, the next added train gets ID 2.

Comment: Could you give us more context? What does `getNextId()` do? How does the caller access the three maps, and what do they do with them?

Comment: Do `Track`, `Train`, and `Coach` all implement a common interface/abstract class?

Comment: That entirely depends on the relation between `Track`, `Train` and `Coach`. From my understanding those three entities don´t have anything in comon so there´s actually not much **generic** here. So what you consider "onviously unnecessary" seems pretty good to me. Basically you should use geerics only if the method relly **is** generic. A method that can handle only three types isn´t really generic.

Comment: @HimBromBeere No, they are not really related but they are all Maps<Integer, ...>. I just didn't want to use three methods getNextTrackId(), getNextTrainId() and getNextCoachId when they all do the same.

Comment: when they all do the same, you should have a common interface with a method like `getId` that all the three classes implement.

Comment: No, the method does the same. The classes are doing completely different things.

Comment: It'd be better to use a `TreeMap`/`NavigableMap`. (Also there's a possible integer overflow, possibly.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I am using a `TreeMap`. Why is there a possible integer overflow?

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake If you used `NavigableMap<Integer, ?> givenMap)`, you wouldn't need to iterate. I don't know the entire context, and you can't tell from the code locally, but if say you could add and remove, id could easily reach 2^31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I would suggest to be as precise as possible. If you know your function works only for a fix set of classes, you shouldn´t make it possible to pass **any** class - which would apply to the `?`-wildcard. Otherwise you´d get some weird runtime-errors, because I may simply provide a `HashMap<Integer, MyOwnClass>` without the compiler complaining. Furthermore you can´t do much on `?`, which will evaluate to `Object`. So if you would need to evauate the maps values some day, you´d have a pretty big issue because you get just `Object`. Changing the methods signature may mor may not be possible at this time, if you have existing clients outside. So I´d strongly suggest not to use the `?` unless you really mean "any arbitrary type of map".

You seem to have three types that all have some kind of an identifier. So best would be to extract an interface for them and use that within your implementation:

```
interface MyInterface { }
class Track : MyInterface { }
class Train : MyInterface { }
class Coach: MyInterface { }
```

Now it´s easy to define your method:

```
public int getNextId(Map<Integer, ? extends MyInterface> givenMap) { ... }
```

Apart from this I can´t see why you even use any map in the first place, when you´re just interested in the **keys**. Better just provide a `List<Integer>` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Write an interface or class (let's call it MyBase) that is inhertited by call three `Track`, `Train` and `Coach`.

Then modify your method:

```
public int getNextId(Map<Integer, ? extends MyBase> givenMap) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: And what if I just use the wildcard `?` instead? Is that bad practice?

Comment: This is better, but I'm not sure if I would call `?` bad practice.

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake Why should you do that? Generally you should be as precise as possible. Otherwise you´d get errors at runtime, because of a type you can´t handle, e.g. a `HashMap<Integer, WeirdClass>`.

Comment: But why should this method create an error at runtime? It just returns an int. Also, how am I supposed to be more precise for the generic type if the classes aren't related at  all. They simply all have a ID that is saved in a map and the getNextId() method gets the next smallest available ID.

Comment: Should I just use `?` then or create three methods with basically the same code? See code of getNextId() in my updated question.

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake If you´re sure the implementaion will never ever care for the maps values, you may of course use the wildcard. But that makes me ask: why even use a map in the first place, when you´re just interested in the maps **keys**?

Comment: The ```?``` without additiona specification allows you to pass any Object. But when the function attempts to call a method of that object that does not exist, then you get a runtime error. E.g. You cannot call the method ```intValue()``` on a String object because that simply does not exist. Specifying the type of class enables the compiler to verify your code before you run it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That's a good point. I haven't even thought about that. I am just using `Set<Integer> ids` as the method parameter now.